# Sliding the data of the line highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have a line Highcharts which is receiving real data, and the amount of points is infinite across the time. I need to split this and delete the oldest points after an determinate amount of points. For example, when it arrives to 50 points, the Highcharts deletes the first point drawn and draws the new one, the number 51.

Is there any option to get this? Revising the Highcharts documentation I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

When adding new points you can use the `shift` parameter to drop off old points when adding the new point. [API description](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint):

> `addPoint` (Object options, [Boolean redraw], [Boolean shift], [Mixed animation])
>
> shift: Boolean
>   Defaults to `false`. When shift is true, one point is shifted off the start of the series as one is appended to the end. Use this option for live charts monitoring a value over time.

For example:

```
// attributes: point options, redraw, shift
series.addPoint([value], true, series.data.length >= 10);
```

Or [see this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/bvn6o3f6/) of it.

Comment: Sorry, I think I missed some information. I'm using highcharts-ng and the function addPoint wasn't working, so I used the push into the array of data. May be I have to call that function in other way?

Comment: Ah okay, that changes things a bit. Not too familiar with Highcharts-ng. See some others are discussing your problem here: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/279